# DOMJudge installation: compile script not generating proper permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, rhel

I am trying to install DOMJudge on a version of Scientific Linux 6.5 (Carbon) adapted and managed by my university. I'm forced to use an RHEL-based Linux version in order to get support from my university for the machine, so switching to Debian-based Linux isn't an option.

I got as far as getting the website up and running and getting the jury interface up. When I try to submit a solution to the 'hello world' example problem, the judgehost spits up the following compiler error (the text below is complete; nothing comes after the colon):

`Compiling failed: no executable was created; compiler output:`

Upon investigation into PREFIX/lib/domjudge/judge/compile.sh and into the judging directory created for the submission, I found that the compiled binary was given permissions that would not allow it to be seen by the compile script at all, causing the script to choke when checking for the existence of the binary after compilation. Here are the permissions and ownership that are granted to the binary when it is generated by compile.sh:

`$ ls -al /usr/local/var/lib/domjudge/judgings/domjudge/c2-s1-j11/compile
total 1440
drwxrwxrwx. 2 domjudge     domjudge    4096 Jul 22 15:07 .
drwx------. 3 domjudge     domjudge    4096 Jul 22 15:07 ..
-rw-rw-r--. 1 domjudge     domjudge     106 Jul 22 15:07 helloworld.cpp
-rwxr-x---. 1 domjudge-run root     1461083 Jul 22 15:07 program`

My judgedaemon user is domjudge and my chroot user is domjudge-run.

My question is this: how can I get compile.sh to set the proper permissions on the binary so it is readable by all users? If I'm barking up the wrong tree and this problem is indicative of a bigger problem in my configuration of DOMJudge, please let me know. I have had no small number of frustrations trying to get DOMJudge to work on Scientific Linux, and I don't doubt that I screwed something up along the way.

Note: I tried to ignore the check within compile.sh to get the script to finish, but once the compilation finishes, the judgedaemon hiccups when trying to copy the binary to the chroot jail because it, again, doesn't have read permissions on the file. So it looks like I have to solve the permissions problem for the rest of the judgedaemon to work.

Comment: I am trying to setup DOMjudge. I am in the initial stage of the setup. So far I have downloaded and extracted domjudge-5.3.2.tar.gz . Now when I am trying to run the ./configure command, the following error is thrown:  configure: error: JSONcpp headers not found (required for submit client). I am using (Red Hat 4.4.7-11). On trying to install libjsoncpp-dev using command:  sudo yum install libjsoncpp-dev, it fails saying 'No package libjsoncpp-dev available.
Error: Nothing to do'. I am not getting a way to proceed. Please help.

Comment: I would recommend reaching out to the domjudge-devel mailing list, as that was how I ultimately resolved my issue. Since the version of DOMJudge you're trying to install is at least 3 years and one major version newer than the one I was setting up, I don't think my solution, nor my knowledge, will be of much help to you. Good luck!

Comment: Sure. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question for anyone who stumbles into this problem in the future.

Asking on the domjudge-devel mailing list yielded a little insight into this problem. It looks like this is a problem specific to the security policy set on the image managed by my university. The hack fix to this problem is to put the following line into the `compile_*.sh` files in lib/judge immediately after the compilation commands:

`chmod -R a+rX .`

Java is a bit more tricky, requiring two of those statements, one after the compilation command and one after the executable program is created.

Note that this is a hack fix; a more correct fix to the problem would probably require finagling with the DOMJudge code itself to accommodate RHEL Linux installations with arbitrary security policies, which is an exercise left to the reader if the hack fix above isn't an option.